# Size argument exception

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am experiencing a first chance excpetion:

[image]

I am completely baffled what is going on here.
As I see in the inspector, Height is 732 and Width is 1114.
Looks absolutely fine to me.

Does anybody have any idea why the error might occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_CompanyLogo.Size` gets or sets the width and height of the control. It doesn't contain the size of the control

Probably you're looking for

```
Dim nSize1 as Size
nSize1.Width = _CompanyLogo.Width
nSize1.Height = _CompanyLogo.Height
```